# getBoundingClientRect seems inaccurate in calculating td width

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am working on a feature which requires me to set CSS width as pixels for each td of a table when a button is clicked. I use getBoundingClientRect to calculate the td width and get the px (e.g. 100px) then set it to the td.style.width. However, it would cause some cells to shift if the table.style.width is already set, but there won't be no shifting if table.style.width is not set. Please see below for the HTML of the table.

```
<table id='mytable' style="border-collapse:collapse;width:300px">
  <tbody>
    <tr height="19" style="height:14.25pt">

      <td style="border:1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);height:14.25pt;width:100px"></td>
      <td style="border:1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);width:100px"></td>
      <td style="border:1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);width:100px"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The weird thing is that I can see the width for each td is: 100, 100, 100, but after applying new width calculated from `getBoundingClientRect().right - getBoundingClientRect().left`, it becomes: 98.5, 100.5, 101. Such inconsistence caused the shifting effect.

What I found is that if `width:300px` doesn't exist in table's CSS, it will work perfectly with no shifting, but if it is there already, I can not just remove it since removing it will cause shifting as well. So I am wondering if there is a way to do this without removing table.style.width.

I created the jsfiddle to repro. What I want is to NOT shift the cells after assigning px to each td. Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/flyingbee2012/udpeq0w9/56/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you default `td` elements' `box-sizing` style property to `border-box` in CSS:

```
td { box-sizing: border-box;}
```

clicking the button in the fiddle doesn't change the width of the table.

Basically the table elements were set up with `content-box` sizing by default. Changing the default to `border-box` in the button click meant the browser had to layout the table again using different sizing rules.

Comment: Thanks, that works and it seems each column doesn't shift as well by defaulting to use `td { box-sizing: border-box;}`, but if it doesn't have this style property set by default, I think it will still cause shifting if we dynamically set it in code? Not sure if there is a way to avoid shifting if box-sizing style property is not set by default?

Comment: You can change the default box model for `td` elements in CSS. Qualify the rule with a class name if you only want to change table cell elements of a particular class. You could also explicitly set `box-model: border-box;` in the style attribute of each `td` element in HTML source. Providing CSS rules is generally preferred as it separates styling from content. As a last resort you could create a `style` element in JavaScript, set its `textContent` to a string of CSS rules, and append it to the body. If you needed to :).